# Data Binding to another .cs file

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listboxitem

In Wpf I want to assign a width to the listbox, where Width should be bound to a method, using RelativeSource Templated Parent Method, which is in another cs file.

I tried using

```
Width={Binding Path=ActualWidth, ParentedElementName}
```

but it is not working.

I have to vary the listbox width based on that method. How can I do that?

Comment: Adding code worth 1000 words.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the `DataContext` property in your code behind. Although it would probably be better to have a ViewModel handle the issue instead of having the View gather its data from different places.